# clickable v-card with excluded area for the v-menu

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using the v-card of Vuetify. I want to make the card clickable so I used the "to" property. It works pretty well. the problem is when I add the menu on the top-right side. When I click on the menu of the card it counts it as I clicked on the v-card which runs other things.

I tried to put the image and text in v-btn but all the other CSS it takes with it is not a real solution. I also tried to have the image and text in [div with router-link](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#tag) but the left side of the menu button is not clickable.

Does the infrastructure have a solution for something like this?

Here is the template of the component.

```
      <v-card :to="'/' + card.name + '/launch'" exact tile>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-menu auto offset-y>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-btn icon v-on="on">
                <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-list>
              <v-list-item
                v-for="(item, i) in card.menuItems" 
                      :key="i" @click="item.action">
                <v-list-item-icon>
                  <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                </v-list-item-icon>
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title>{{ item.text }}</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </v-list-item>
            </v-list>
          </v-menu>
        </v-card-actions>
          <v-img :src="card.image" class="mx-auto" width="72"></v-img>
          <v-card-title class="pb-0 mb-3 justify-center" style="font-family:'Google Sans',Roboto,sans-serif; line-height:1.1;">{{ card.title }}</v-card-title>
          <v-card-text class="text--secondary rtl">{{ card.content }}</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Zim Answer below. Related: https://www.sitepoint.com/event-bubbling-javascript/. & https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `stop` [event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) on the menu @click item action, and `.prevent` on the menu btn..

```
      <v-card :to="'/launch'" exact tile>
            <v-card-actions>
                <v-menu auto offset-y>
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                        <v-btn icon v-on="on" v-on:click.prevent>
                            <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                    </template>
                    <v-list>
                        <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" @click.stop="item.action">
                            <v-list-item-icon>
                                <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
                            </v-list-item-icon>
                            <v-list-item-content>
                                <v-list-item-title>{{ item.text }}</v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item-content>
                        </v-list-item>
                    </v-list>
                </v-menu>
            </v-card-actions>
            <v-img src="//placehold.it/200" class="mx-auto" width="72"></v-img>
            <v-card-title class="pb-0 mb-3 justify-center" style="font-family:'Google Sans',Roboto,sans-serif; line-height:1.1;">Title</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text class="text--secondary rtl">Card text...</v-card-text>
       </v-card>
```

https://codeply.com/p/viy24oqC2j